# how to move all the Layouts up when scrolling more in the list view in android

Tags: android, scroll

i have a fragment which has a stationary Image View at the top , some linear layouts to display the texts and List View at the Bottom. i want the entire screen to go up(that stationary Image View and middle part) when i scroll down in the List View.
I tried to place all layouts in a single Linear Layout and put it inside Scroll View since it has only one direct child..but that makes only the List view scroll able.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CoordinatorLayout and scrolling behaviour from the design library.You can find a great tutorial [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en)